# Unable to 'check' datagridview checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I've added a checkbox column to my datagridview.  Problem is I cannot check the checkboxes. 
I have removed all read only from columns. I add this column using the Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There is a checkbox in the DataGridView task menu named as "Enable Editing". It must be checked.

[image]